# How can we tell if Simpson’s rule is an underestimate or overestimate of the area under a curve?

Tags: simpsons-rule

Context: high school math

Question: integrating a semicircle $y= \sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$ using five function values with Simpson’s rule gives me $0.7709$. The exact value is $0.785$.

I understand for the trapezoidal rule we can predict if it under/overestimates the area based on the curve’s concavity.

So I wonder if there's a simple way to predict whether Simpson’s rule over/underestimates a curve like this? (I understand Simpson’s rule holds equality for linear and cubic equations)

Edited to add: I have used the formula for error in the comments below and I’m struggling with finding the maximum absolute value of the fourth derivative since there is a vertical asymptomate at x=1 there, please see below graphs of first, second, third and fourth derivatives of the curve

[image]

Comment: From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) article, the error in Simpson's rule is $ -\frac{(b - a)^5}{2880} f^{(4)}(\xi)$, where $\xi$ is some value between $a$ and $b$. So the error depends on the fourth derivative of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.